# gvim: Easy copying into system clipboard

Tags: vim, clipboard, ubuntu-10.10

I am using gVim on Ubuntu 10.10. I want to copy (yank) text to the system clipboard, so that the copied text is available in other applications.

This works with `"+y`. But I want to have it working with `y`.

I have tried to map `y` to `"+y` but then `yy` doesn't work anymore (since it produces `"+y"+y`).

I have also tried
`:set clipboard=unnamed`
but this works only the other direction: Text in the system clipboard I can paste with `p`.

Comment: I just use different mappings for dealing with the clipboard, and keep the normal functionality of the `y` command

Comment: In case it's unclear to some, "+y means you have to type ", +, y (" is the register symbol, + is clipboard register, y is yank)

Answer (score 16):

Did you try to map with this command:

```
noremap y "+y
```

? This mapping contains a serious mistake: it maps `y` in normal, visual and operator-pending modes, while you need only normal and visual modes. Use the following:

```
nnoremap y "+y
vnoremap y "+y
```

Also try `set clipboard=unnamedplus` (it requires at least vim-7.3.74). `set clipboard=unnamed` works in both directions, but it sets «mouse» (`*`) register which is different from clipboard register (`+`).

Answer (score 12):

Most online solutions simply tell you to map `y` to `"+y`. But sometimes the issue is `"+y` doesn't even work. You do need to check what features your `vim` has been compiled with.

Try the steps below:

1. Open your terminal, run `vim –-version | grep xterm_clipboard`
2. Check the sign before `xterm_clipboard`, if it’s a `+` (plus sign), go to step 4.
3. If it’s a - (minus sign), run `sudo apt-get install vim-gnome`, then `sudo update-alternatives –config vim`, select `vim.gnome` in the list (You should use the proper command that corresponds to your system). Run command `vim –-version | grep xterm_clipboard` again, now you should be able to get `+` (plus sign).
4. Check whether your system clipboard uses `+` (plus sign) or `*` (star sign) register of vim, this depends on the OS you're using, sometimes they’re equivalent. How to check? Just copy some random text, then open `vim` and type `:reg`, check which register shows the string you just copied. If it’s a `+` (plus sign), add `set clipboard=unnamedplus` to your `.vimrc`. If it’s a `*` (star sign), add `set clipboard=unnamed`.
5. Test it out. Copy something inside `vim`, and then type `:reg` to check if the system clipboard has changed. If it does, your will get whatever is in that register when you paste outside of `vim`.

Comment: @CHID glad to be of help

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. But what do the commands in step 3 do? (And why does it work?)

Answer (score 4):

I have the very same idea as you, but I did it for years.

```
nnoremap yy yy"+yy
vnoremap y ygv"+y
```

Note that now `yy` command does two things: First it yank to register as normal, and then it yank to `"` register (system clipboard). The `y` command does the same thing. This is because I want to keep the multiple clipboard functionality of Vim.

For pasting from system clipboard, I used to have `noremap gp "+p` (global pasting), but now I use the excellent plugin Yankring.

Answer (score 2):

Select some text in [visual mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html) and it will be inserted into the system clipboard (the one where you middle-click to paste, I cannot recall the exact name).

If you `set mouse=a` you can use the mouse for visual selection like you would in many other applications.

Comment: For some reason, the middle-click copy of "visually-selected" text doesn't work for me in cells of a jupyter notebook in Firefox. Pasting after `"+y` works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I can sometimes copy from gvim to the system clipboard and sometimes not.  I found a workaround, though I don't understand the underlying problem.  If I copy text in another application (e.g. Notepad, as I am on Windows 7), then I can copy text from gvim and paste it elsewhere.  It looks I need do this for each copy out of gvim.