# paste text with "\n" trouble in windows gVim

Tags: vim

If I paste text that ends with `"\n"` (eg. `"aaa\n"`) into quotes (eg. "") or tags (eg. `<foo></foo>`), It will paste like this:

```
aaa
""

aaa
<foo></foo>
```

but it should be:

```
"aaa
"

<foo>aaa
</foo>
```

Does anybody know what's the matter?

Comment: gvim on windows, use ^r+ is ok

Answer (score 1):

Are you pasting by typing `"+p`? This should work as expected. See these links:

- [gvim: Easy copying into system clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532110/gvim-easy-copying-into-system-clipboard)
- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard
- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/gvim-cut-copy-paste-374760/
- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/how-to-copy-and-paste-things-between-vim-and-system-clipboard-669721/

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that the register from which you are pasting is not characterwise but probably linewise. you've probably pasted the text with `yy` or `Vy` or `dd` or `Vd`. That's a feature that enables you for example to use `ddp` to swap two lines.

If you want to turn the register to a linewise register you can do:

```
:call setreg('"', @", 'c')
```

then `P` or `p` will insert what you pasted characterwise.

Of course if you are pasting with another register (`"ap` for example) you'll have to modify the first and second arguments to `setreg`.

Another way to copy lines: if you want to yank a line characterwise including the newline, you can do `0y$`.

References:

- `:help setreg()`
- `:help linewise-register`